# Nested array issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array["MyArray",
  {
      "isLoaded":true,
      "items":
      [{
          "id":"4",
          "name":"ProductA",
          "manufacturer":"BrandA",
          "quantity":1,
          "price":"25"
      },{
          "id":"1",
          "name":"ProductB",
          "manufacturer":"BrandB",
          "quantity":5,
          "price":"20"
      }],
      "coupons":null
  }
 ]
```

I need to load product names and their quantity from the array.

```
const result = [key, value].map((item) => `${item.name} x ${item.quantity}`);
```

Comment: `Array["MyArray",` ??? makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way to achieve the desired result:

```
const getProductsAndQuantity = ([k , v] = arr) => (
    v.items.map(it => `${it.name} x ${it.quantity}`)
);
```

**How to use it within the context of the question?**

```
localforage.iterate(function(value, key, iterationNumber) {
  console.log([key, value]);
  const val2 = JSON.parse(value);
  if (val2 && val2.items && val2.items.length > 0) { 
      console.log(val2.items.map(it => `${it.name} x ${it.quantity}`).join(', '))
  };
});
```

**How it works?**

1. Among the parameters listed in the question ie, `value, key, iterationNumber`, only `value` is required.
2. The above method accepts the key-value pair as an array (of 2 elements) closely matching the `console.log([key, value]);` in the question
3. It uses only `v` (which is an object). On `v`, it accesses the `prop` named `items` and this `items` is an Array.
4. Next, `.map` is used to iterate through the Array and return each product's `name` and `quantity` in the desired/expected format.

**Test it out on code-snippet:**

```js
const arr = [
  "MyArray",
  {
    "isLoaded": true,
    "items": [{
      "id": "4",
      "name": "ProductA",
      "manufacturer": "BrandA",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": "25"
    }, {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "ProductB",
      "manufacturer": "BrandB",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": "20"
    }],
    "coupons": null
  }
];

const getProductsAndQuantity = ([k, v] = arr) => (
  v.items.map(
    it => `${it.name} x ${it.quantity}`
  )
);

console.log(getProductsAndQuantity());
```

Comment: updated the section. Please try now

Answer (score 0):

I understood. You should learn about array methods such as map, filter, reduce.  Here you go...

```js
const items = [{
              "id":"4",
              "name":"ProductA",
              "manufacturer":"BrandA",
              "quantity":1,
              "price":"25"
          },{
              "id":"1",
              "name":"ProductB",
              "manufacturer":"BrandB",
              "quantity":5,
              "price":"20"
          }];
          
const result = items.map((item) => `${item.name} x ${item.quantity}`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question to say that the input is an array of objects, each containing an array of items.  The key is that a nested array requires a nested loop. So, we iterate the objects and their internal items (see the lines commented `//outer loop` and `// inner loop` below)

Also, half-guessing from the context, it looks like the that the OP aims to assemble a sort of invoice for each object.  First a demo of that, (and see below for the version simplified to exactly what the OP asks)...

```js
const addInvoice = obj => {
  let total = 0;
  // inner loop
  obj.invoice = obj.items.map(i => {
    let subtotal = i.quantity * i.price;
    total += subtotal
    return `name: ${i.name}, qty: ${i.quantity}, unit price: ${i.price}, subtotal: ${subtotal}`
  });
  obj.invoice.push(`invoice total: ${total}`);
}

const objects = [{
  "isLoaded": true,
  "items": [{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ProductA",
    "manufacturer": "BrandA",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": "25"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "ProductB",
    "manufacturer": "BrandB",
    "quantity": 5,
    "price": "20"
  }],
  "coupons": null
}]

// outer loop
objects.forEach(addInvoice);
console.log(objects);
```

If my guess about the goal went to far, just remove the unit price, subtotal and total lines from the `invoice` function...

```js
const objects = [{
  "isLoaded": true,
  "items": [{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ProductA",
    "manufacturer": "BrandA",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": "25"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "ProductB",
    "manufacturer": "BrandB",
    "quantity": 5,
    "price": "20"
  }],
  "coupons": null
}]

const summaryString = obj => {
  return obj.items.map(i => `${i.name}, ${i.quantity}`);
}
const strings = objects.map(summaryString);
console.log(strings);
```